# Generating a three dimensional data structure with purrr map

Tags: r, purrr

I have a list that contains 1000 simulations, each has a sample of dimension 1 x 100:

```
library(purrr)
simulations <- rerun(1000, rbinom(100, 100, 0.8)) %>% set_names(paste0("sim", 1:1000))
```

I have another list of numbers of length 500 - or 500 steps:

```
# Each entry is a step from 1 to 500
foo <- rnorm(500, 200,75) %>% set_names(paste0("step", 1:500))
```

For each vector in `simulations` I want multiply it by `foo`. If we take the first sample vector from `simulations` we get:

```
values <- simulations$sim1 %*% t(foo)
```

Where `values` is of dimension 100 x 500. I'd like to generate a data structure that is flattened along the three dimensions `sim`, `step` and `values`:

| sim | step | values |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | step1 | v1 |
| .. | .. | .. |
| 1 | step500 | v500 |
| 1 | .. | .. |
| 1 | step1 | v501 |
| 1 | .. | .. |
| 1 | step500 | v1000 |
| 1 | .. | .. |
| 1 | step1 | v50000 |
| 2 | step1 | v1 |
| .. | .. | .. |
| .. | .. | .. |
| 1000 | step500 | v50000 |

So ultimately I should end up with a data structure that has 1000 x 500 x 100 = 50m rows. If possible I'd like to use an approach using `purrr::map`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `purr` you can do this way:

```
# vector multiplication of each simulation with foo
map(simulations, `%*%`, t(foo)) %>% 

  # set result to dataframe and row-bind them
  map_dfr(as.data.frame, .id = "sim") %>% 

  # reshape to get the result you need
  tidyr::pivot_longer(-sim, names_to = "step")

#> # A tibble: 50'000'000 x 3
#>    sim   step    value
#>    <chr> <chr>   <dbl>
#>  1 sim1  step1  22321.
#>  2 sim1  step2  21469.
#>  3 sim1  step3  17064.
#>  4 sim1  step4   4216.
#>  5 sim1  step5  20458.
#>  6 sim1  step6  16251.
#>  7 sim1  step7  15630.
#>  8 sim1  step8   7445.
#>  9 sim1  step9  13624.
#> 10 sim1  step10 19202.
#> # ... with 49,999,990 more rows
```

Answer (score 3):

In `base R`, we may loop over the `list` with `lapply`, do the computation with `foo`, `stack` to a two column data.frame and then create the `sim` column by `cbind`ing with the sequence of the `list` and `rbind`

```
out <- do.call(rbind, Map(cbind, sim = seq_along(simulations), 
     lapply(simulations, \(x) stack(as.data.frame(x %*% t(foo))))))
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it might be

```
library(tidyverse)
  
imap_dfr(
  simulations,
  ~ data.frame(.x %*% t(foo)) |>
    pivot_longer(cols = everything()) |>
    mutate(sim = as.integer(str_replace(.y, "sim", ""))) |>
    relocate(sim)
)
```